# Why is my message app not sorting by recent message?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

Ever since I had a storage issue, my messages app no longer puts new messages at the top of the messages list.

When i get a message from someone , sms or imessage it is added to their conversation whereever that person happens to be in the list rather than moving to the top which it used to do.

Have I accidentally put on a setting? If so can I turn it off?

Comment: Did you maybe change time, language or region settings?

Comment: No, but thanks for the suggestion.  Took a look just incase but all normal